# Create/Update Page Tabs - Using API

Tags: facebook-apps

I am very new to facebook application development and gone through the 'Getting Started' guides and Beginner tutorials. Actually it's good to place to start and familiarize the terms and core knowledge about app development.

There is a customer requirement where they can able to create/update custom tabs(for pages) for all of their customer's facebook account.

I just need to make sure that I am progressing on the correct path.

1) Create an App
2) Customize the permissions for accessing user's pages/tabs
3) Create/Update/remove/maintain the tabs with this application

Please advise if I missed anything here.  It would be helpful if you point any good places to start/architecture etc...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dup of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3757084/manage-facebook-page-tab-apps-via-open-graph-api/ and http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7726219/create-and-configure-facebook-apps-via-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate tabs for a page, you need the **manage_pages** permission.

For more details on what you can do with tabs using the Graph API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page#tabs